# Update firebase service-workers for old users

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I've just installed firebase in my app. So I registered service workers for tens of thousands of users to receive background notifications.
How can I update all of them?

#### The problems why I want to update them:

- I have hardcoded notification icon in service worker and now I want to get it from payload
- I changed api version, now passing parameters in `payload.data.title` instead of `payload.json.title`

Can I update already registered service workers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service Workers are updated according to their update lifecycle ([see docs here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#updates)). Specifically from the docs, a service worker is updated when any of these happen:

- A navigation to an in-scope page.
- A functional events such as `push` and `sync`, unless there's been an update check within the previous 24 hours.
- Calling `.register()` only if the service worker URL has changed. However, you should avoid changing the worker URL.

Comment: "A navigation to an in-scope page" there is not chance for this, it was landing page.
As I read, when I sent new push notification service worker automatically refreshes, right?

Comment: I'm not a service worker expert, but it sounds like yes, if you receive a push the service worker will update itself if it's been > 24 hours.